# Which Purana mentions about Sati's death?

Tags: vishnu, scripture, shiva, puranas, sati-goddess

The story of Prajapati Daksha's daughter, Sati, married Lord Shiva is well known. And also that, Daksha organized a great yajna, in which Sati jumped into the sacrificial fire and committed suicide. Sati died, but her corpse did not burn. Virabhadra was sent by Lord Shiva to decapitate Daksha for being responsible for Sati's death and Shiva forgave by resurrecting him. The wild, grief-stricken Shiva wandered the universe with Sati's corpse. Finally, the lord Vishnu dismembered the body of Sati into 52 parts, each of which became Shakti Peetha, temple to a form of the Goddess.

This is the well know story of Sati and origins of the Shakti Peethas.

I would like to know the source of this popular story.

Comment: It is in Shiva mahapurana, andhra mahabhagavatham and many other

Comment: More than one Puranas.

Comment: @ Rickross Good to learn that more the one dicuss about this story. I would like you to support me with the transcript .Atleast the basic minimum.

Comment: I think both Shiva and Skanda Purana don't mention this. May be Shakta texts mention this incident.

Answer (score 8):

Lord Vishnu cutting off Sati's body in pieces and the subsequent creation of the Shakti Pithas is described in [book 7,chapter XXX of the Devi Bhagavatam.](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam37-5.htm)

> He, the Ocean of Mercy, destroyed the sacrifice of Daksa, cut off his
>   head and instead placed the head of a goat, brought him back to life
>   and thus made the Gods free from all fears. He, the Deva of the Devas,
>   then became very much distressed and going to the place of sacrifice,
>   began to weep in great sorrow. He saw that the body of the Intelligent
>   Satî was being burnt in the fire of the Chitâ. He cried aloud :– Oh my
>   Satî! Oh My Satî! And taking Her body on His neck, began to roam in
>   different countries, like a mad man. Seeing that, Brahmâ and the other
>   Devas became very anxious **and Bhagavân Visnu cut off the body to
>   pieces by His arrows. Wherever the parts fell, S’ankara remained there
>   in so many different forms.**

King Janamejaya enquired:

> 51-52. Janamejaya said :– Where, in what places the several parts of
>   the Satî fell? What are the names of those Siddhapîthas? And what is
>   their number? Kindly describe these in detail, O Great Muni
>
> 53-102. Vyâsa said :– O King! I will now describe those Pîthas (Sacred
>   places), the mere hearing of which destroys all the sins of men. Hear.
>   I describe duly those places where the persons desiring to get lordly
>   powers and to attain success ought to worship and meditate on the
>   Devî. O Mahârâja! The face of Gaurî fell in Kâs’î; She is well known
>   there by the name Vis’âlâksî; that which fell in Naimisâranya became
>   known by the name of Linga Dhârinî. This Mahâ Mâyâ is known in Prayâg
>   (Allahabad) by the name of Lalitâ Devî; in Gandha Mâdan, by the name
>   of Kâmukî; in the southern Mânasa, by Kumudâ; in the northern Mânasa,
>   by Visvakâmâ, the Yielder of all desires; in Gomanta, by Gomatî and in
>   the mountain of Mandara, She became known by the name of Kâmachârinî.
>   The Devî is known in Chaitraratha, by the name of of Madotkatâ; in
>   Hastinâpura, by Jayantî; in Kânyakubja by the name of Gaurî; in the
>   Malaya Mountain, by Rambhâ; in the Ekâmrapîtha, by Kîrtimatî, in
>   Vis’ve, by the name of Vis’ves’varî; in Puskara, by the name of
>   Puruhûtâ. She is known as Sanmârga Dâyinî in the Kedâra Pîtha; as
>   Mandâ, in the top of the Himâlayâs; and as Bhadrakarnikâ in Gokarna.
>   She is known as Bhavânî in Sthanes’vara, as Vilvapatrikâ in Vilvake;
>   as Mâdhavi in S’rîs’aila; as Bhadrâ in Bhadres’vara. She is known as
>   Jarâ in Varâha S’aila; as Kamalâ in Kamalâlaya; as Rudranî in Rudra
>   Kotî; as Kâlî in Kâlanjara; She is known as Mahâ Devî in S’âlagrâma,
>   as Jalapriyâ in S’ivalingam; as Kapilâ in Mahâlingam, as Mukutes’varî
>   in Mâkota. As Kumarî in Mâyâpurî, as Lalitâmbikâ in Santânâ; as
>   Mangalâ in Gayâ Ksetra, as Vimalâ in Purusottama. As Utpalâksî in
>   Sahasrâksa; as Mahotpalâ in Hiranyâksa; as Amoghâksî in the Vipâsâ
>   river; as Pâtalâ in Pundra Vardhana. As Nârâyanî in Supârs’va, as
>   Rudra Sundarî in Trikûta; as Vipulâ Devî in Vipulâ; as Kalyânî in
>   Malayâchala. As Ekavîrâ, in Sahyâdri; as Chandrikâ in Haris’chandra;
>   as Ramanâ in Râma Tîrtha; as Mrigâvatî in the Yamunâ. As Kotivî in
>   Kotatîrtha; as Sugandhâ in Mâdhavavana; as Trisandhyâ in the Godâvarî;
>   as Ratipriyâ in Gangâdvâra. As S’ubhânandâ in S’iva Kundam, as Nandinî
>   in Devîkâtata; as Rukminî in Dvâravatî; as Râdhâ in Brindâvana. As
>   Devakî in Mathurâ; as Parames’varî in Pâtâla; as Sîtâ in Chitrakuta;
>   as Vindhyâdhivâsinî in the Vindhyâ range. O King! As Mahâlaksmî in the
>   sacred place of Karavîra, as Umâ Devî in Vinâyaka; as Ârogyâ in
>   Vaidyânâtha; as Mahes’varî in Mahâkâla, as Abhayâ in all the Usna
>   tîrthas, as Nitambâ in the Vindhyâ mountain; as Mândavî in Mândavya;
>   as Svâhâ in Mâhes’varîpûra. As Prachandâ in Chhagalanda, as Chandikâ
>   in Amarakantaka; as Varârohâ in Somes’vara; as Puskarâvatî in
>   Prabhâsa. As Devamâtâ in Sarasvatî; as Parâvârâ in Samudrtata; as
>   Mahâbhâgâ in Mahâlayâ, as Pingales’varî in Payosnî. As Simhikâ in
>   Kritas’aucha; as Atis’ânkârî in Kârtika; as Lolâ in Utpalâvartaka; as
>   Subhadrâ in S’ona Sangam. As the Mother Laksmî in Siddhavana; as
>   Anangâ in Bhâratâs’rama; as Vis’vamukhî in Jâlandhara; as Târâ in the
>   Kiskindhya mountain. As Pustî in Devadâru Vana; as Medhâ in
>   Kâs’mîramandalam......

Not quoted all the Pithas but there are 108 of them in all.

> O Janamejaya! Thus I have mentioned to you the **one hundred and eight
>   pîthas (sacred places or seats of the Deity) and as many Devîs**

Comment: Do you know which Purana mentions Vishnu using Sudarshana Chakra to cut Sati's body?

Comment: As i said in the answer,if the above slokas are from the Kalika Purana (which is my guess)then it mentions that story too i.e Vishnu cutting Sati's body into parts.

Comment: There's no reason to downvote it as user wanted to know "death story of Goddess Sati". Anyways, i nullified it by upvoting. OP should highlight if he primarily wants to know about Vishnu cutting Sati's body.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks and yes Sati's death and other parts of the story are covered in my answer.Even the last part is correct but i do not have proofs now.

Comment: @TheDestroyer The Devi Bhagavatam mentions the story..hence i have removed all other references from my answer..

Comment: Yes. Saw it. Good answer. I actually read only 2 books of Devi Bhagavatam. BTW, do you know individual stories or legends of 52 Shakti peetas? We can provide  info about them like 12 [tag:jyotirlinga] s (as Q&A). Also, questions about Devi are very less on this site when compared to other Gods.

Comment: Thanks,Yes you are right ....About the 51 peethas i know few legends from a bengali book..

Comment: Then you can post Q&A discussing their legends and importance :)