# If Sati's body was fully burned, then how 51 shaktipeeth came into existence?

Tags: shiva-purana, shakti, sati-goddess

I have read that (according to Shiva Purana) Sati's body was turned into ashes.

> 6-7. She desired to cast-off her body due to her anger with Dakṣa. She desired to burn off the body and retain the pure wind by yogic means. In this posture she remembered the feet of her lord and nothing else.
>
> 8. Her body divested of its sins fell in the yogic fire and was reduced to ashes, O excellent sage, in accordance with her own wish.
>
> Source; Chapter 30 - Satī’s casting off of her body and the subsequent disorder
>
> https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226050.html

If that is true, how did Shaktipeethas come into existence?

I'm little bit confused about it.

Comment: Must be wrong translation from Sanskrit to English. This usually happens.

Comment: I guess it was not burnt. After Sati left her mortal body, Lord Shiva roamed around carrying the body of Sati. That is when Lord Vishnu cut the body of Sati with His Sudarshana chakra. Wherever, a fragment of Sati's body fell, we have a Shakti peetha. For example, it is said that the eyes of Sati fell in Kanchipuram in Tamil Nadu and we have Kamakshi temple there which is a Shakti peetha.

Comment: very tricky question indeed.  very difficult to answer :-)@aniket kumar singh

Comment: There is a [different story](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/which-purana-mentions-about-satis-death/15937#15937) too.

Comment: The problem with the story is that in Shiva Purana it was mentioned that Sati's body was reduced to ashes.  Then the question becomes genuine as to how the ashes can be cut into pieces, be it 51 or 108@TriyugiNarayanMani

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I think these two Puranas narrates the stories of two different Kalpas.